# Can someone check my PHP script? syntax error, unexpected '}'

Tags: php, html, css

I got an error in the last line `<?php } ?>` it says syntax error, unexpected '}'

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) { 
            //echo "You are logged in!";
             include_once 'database.php';
             $edit_state = false; ?>
                <h2>Welcome!</h2>
                <form method="POST" action="process.php">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label>Reference Number: <label>
                    <input type="text" name="reference_no" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label>Action Taken<label>
                    <input type="text" name="action_taken" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                <?php if ($edit_state == false): ?>
                    <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn">Save</button>
                <?php else: ?> 
                    <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn">Update</button>
                <?php endif ?>
                </div>
            </form>
        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you missing a `;` after endif at `<?php endif ?>`

change this `<?php endif ?>` to `<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: You should repost their full code, as there are several `if` blocks.  But your correct!  I usually mark it with a comment.  like this `<?php endif; //fixed here ?>` within the full code they posted.

Comment: I did put a `;` still getting the same error.

Comment: I found the error. its on another php file. Thanks for answering!